# OnSubmit = false triggering another form on the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have 2 forms on the same MVC page. They look like this :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("InstructionSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
        }
```

and

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ECN", "Search", new { id = "searchForm", onsubmit = "return checkFormEcn()" }))
        { 
        }
```

They're following each other in the code, so, no nest here ;)

So, i'd like to prevent the second one (With "ECN"), from beeing submited when my `checkFormEcn` returns false.

This is alright, but when the 2nd form's submit is denied by my javascript function, my first form (With "Search") is automatically submitted, without touching anything.

Any idea of how i could prevent this ?

Comment: Is the second form nested inside the first?

Comment: Nope, they're following each other

Comment: @brso05 i'll try to, wait a minute :)

Comment: @LeZohan68 use the same `onsubmit = "return checkFormEcn()"` for the first form...

Comment: It's not working. The first one is still triggered

Comment: @LeZohan68 if `checkFormEcn()` returns false then it shouldn't submit...Unless you are explicitly submitting somewhere within the `checkFormEcn()` method.

Comment: I know x). Now i got this error message : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when i submit the 2nd one. And this errors happens on the closing bracket of the FIRST form. I don't get it ...

Answer (score 0):

If you also don't want the first form to submit when the second one doesn't submit then add this to the first form:

```
onsubmit = "return checkFormEcn()"


@using (Html.BeginForm("InstructionSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return checkFormEcn()" }))
{
}
```

Comment: I patched this. With a "dirty hack".
I added this `<button type="submit" style="display: none" id="EcnSubmitBtn"></button>` into the second form, this `<button type="click" onclick="checkFormEcn()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>` just after the closing bracket of the second one, and instead of returning false and true in my js function, i trigger or not a click event on the form ...
Not proud of the solution, but until i find something better, i'll keep this x)
Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

i think u can easy have HTML button outside the form and onclick event you submit form

search

@using (Html.BeginForm("ECN", "Search", new { id = "searchForm" }))
  {

}

same as InstructionSearch form